# Can't show the whole long line in GoLand console

Tags: go, goland

I wrote the code as follows:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111" +
       "1111111111111111111111111111")
}
```

Though I have unselected the checkbox of "use soft wraps in console":

[image]

The output in GoLand console is:

[image]

The output in windows cmd is:

[image]

What can I do to show the whole long line in GoLand console, just in windows cmd?

Comment: What version are you on? Did you try the latest 2020.1.2?

Comment: I'm using the GoLand 2019.2.5. The latest 2020.1.2 does not solve the problem but disabling go.run.processes.with.pty registry does help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because GoLand 2020.1 enabled pty on Windows but default and old settings were not correctly migrated.

Before doing the workaround below, upgrade to 2020.1.2, which should solve the issue. If it doesn't, then proceed with the workaround below.

Disable `go.run.processes.with.pty` registry key in `Ctrl+Shift+A | Registry...` and this will be solved.

For more details, see [the related issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-9168).

Comment: Disabling go.run.processes.with.pty works! Thanks a lot!